# Amazon s3 upload file to bucket from third party website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can we use amazon v4 API of amazon: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html but I don't think it's useful for my purpose.

What I want is, there are some files on websites, I want those files to be uploaded in amazon s3 bucket without downloading them first on my local computer, current scenario is like this:

The third-party website provides downloaded link of file -> download file to my computer > upload to amazon s3

Can we eliminate the middle one so it become like this:

The third-party website provides downloaded link of file -> upload to amazon s3

Comment: S3 doesn't have a mechanism to download files from a remote location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid the "download" part unless that "other website" is willing to do upload for you.

But you can eliminate your local network connection from the equation and do download/upload using EC2 instance in the same region as your bucket.

```
$ wget https://example.com/example.txt
$ aws s3 cp example.txt s3://mybucket
```

Your EC2 instance should have the role, allowing it to interact with S3.

You can do the same thing with Lambda, but you'll be limited by the size of the filesystem of the lambda runtime.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I need!

Answer (score 0):

> The third-party website provides downloaded link of file -> upload to amazon s3

If the 3rd party doesn't push the content "itself", you will need an actor/service/logic which downloads and uploads the data.

The "logic" means some compute resources - c2, ecs, lambda, batch.. it's the same download/upload process, just the traffic doesn't need to go through your computer. Every option has its pros and cons (e. g. lambda may be the cheapest for occasional tasks, but it has its limits)

You did not specify what initiates the upload (regular scan? event? on-demand?), that may affect your options too.